# unable to invoke Cypress custom commands in test files

Tags: javascript, cypress, session-cookies, cypress-custom-commands

I am working on managing the session cookie for each test case by setting it in beforeEach() and afterEach() block.

Using the below custom session command in **C:\cypress\support\commands.js**

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('saveSessionStorage', () => {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key] = localStorage[key];
  });
});

Cypress.Commands.add('restoreSessionStorage', () => {
  Object.keys(LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY).forEach(key => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key]);
  });
});
```

And imported in **cypress/Support/Index.js**

```
import './commands'
```

In **test.js** file used custom commands as below

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreSessionStorage()

  });
  
  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveSessionStorage()
  });
```

But I am getting the below error while implementing the custom commands such has ***cy.restoreSessionStorage() & cy.saveSessionStorage()***  in **test.js** file as below

> Property 'restoreSessionStorage' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.ts(2339)

and

> Property 'saveSessionStorage' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.ts(2339)

What could be the problem? Please help

Project Structure: [image]

Comment: Is your project a typescript project ?

Comment: No, its JavaScript

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your project structure.

Comment: Added the screenshot of Project Structure

Comment: It looks like it thinks its a typescript project, from the error it refers to ts files and this is fixed in TS by `Cypress.Commands.add('customCommand', customCommand);`

Comment: I see you have tsconfig.json, why do you need that ? try to remove it